# Can someone checkout the structure of my SpringBoot?

Tags: spring-boot

I am following some projects from the book *Domain Driven Design with Spring Boot: Enterprise Application from scratch* and I am getting errors :

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

I am using the kindle version of the book and its structure doesn't help at all.
Can someone please advise if the structure of my files is OK?

[image]

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Beside that Controller can be removed when using RestController annotation everything looks fine. Can you please post the stack trace of the error you get?

Comment: The error you are getting is just the default warning which says you did not explicitly configured an error page. If you configure `/error` mapping and redirect to an error page than you can use `${errorMsg}` to show the error to the user if you like. Other than this, if you can post your entire stack trace it will be easy to say where the real error is.

Comment: For what endpoint you are getting the error message. You would get that if you used an incorrect endpoint.